# How to show version number when using 'Export to Excel' command

Tags: 2013, excel, export, versioning

my firm is transferring a project to another firm. The new firm wants a list of all of our files. 
I went into our sharepoint library and selected "Export to Excel" which returned a spreadsheet with the file path, link to the file, file size, date created, and last modified by. 
I need that to also indicate Version number.

Is this possible, either OOTB, or programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the version column to the current view and selected "Export to Excel".=) Or of course you can do that programmatically using [SPFile.UIVersionLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.uiversionlabel.aspx) for example:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Your site url"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList docs = web.Lists["Your library name"];
        foreach (SPFile file in docs.RootFolder.Files)
        {
            var fileVersion = file.UIVersionLabel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the version column is already in the current view. I will try making a custom view and see if that works. As well as forward this to our developer.

Answer (score 2):

The version number does not display when using Export to Excel.

You have several options:

- Use a calculated column with value =Version. This formula will work despite the column not being available. [Not recommended due to caching and freezing during export].
- Write a VBA function within your connected spreadsheet which will import the version info after the initial import. [Also not recommended because each user would be required to save a local version of the file for every required list.]
- Write a PowerShell script which prompts for Web URL and List name, and specify some default columns. Users could run this locally, or you could make list specific and automate it with a scheduled task which can email required users. [Recommended but still has its pitfalls.]