# Report Version Numbers into CSV

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I was wondering if it was possible to obtain a list of all the minor and major versions within a library in Sharepoint (Office 365 version), through script or otherwise. 
This is so we can see what documents are nearing the minor version limit and publish a new major version (it's how the company operates). Ideally, this would be exported to a CSV file so we can sort the information by minor version number (preferably in two columns).

My PowerShell isn't all that great, so I was wondering if someone has come across this before or would be willing to share a script that could work? Or perhaps a tool that would do this for us?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would add version field to the view, export to excel, use data to text on the version column, delimited by period, then hide everything where the second column is 0.

Comment: I've tried this, but the version column doesn't appear, unfortunately.

Comment: The answers to this question provide some solutions: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85540/how-to-show-version-number-when-using-export-to-excel-command